# Whole data group divided by percentage representation of the whole

Tags: python

How to create the data set below in python?

**Data Set:**

> A:  0 - 20% of readings
>   B: 20% - 40% of readings
>   C: 40% - 60% of readings
>   D: 60% - 80% of readings
>   E: 80% - 100% of readings

**Data:**

```
values = [68,68,69,68,69,70,71,75,72,73,72,72,73,72,72,73,70,71,73,72,72,71,69,68
          69,68,69,68,69,68,68,68,68,69,68,69,70,71,75,72,69,68,68,68,69,68,69,70
          71,75,72,69,68,69,68,69,68,69,68,68,60,60,61,60,61,65,69,69,72,73,72,72
          73,72,72,73,70,71,73,75,78,80,82,84,87,84,84,83,82,79,78,76,74,73,72,72
          72,71,75,72,69,68,68,68,69,68,69,70,71,75,72,69,68,69,68,69,68,69,68,68]
```

**Example:**

```
A = [68,68,69,68,69,70,71,75,72,73]
```

That represents 20% of the whole

**Note:** I know that it is possible to calculate manually using percentage accounts based on the total, but I would like to use some library to get more performance

**Mathematical resolution**

```
@staticmethod        
def while_generator(start, n):
    i = start
    while i <= n:
        yield i
        i += 1

@staticmethod
def Kmodeling():

    X,Y = data() # Create X and Y

    total = len(Y)
    a1 = int((total / 100) * 20)
    a2 = int((total / 100) * 40)
    a3 = int((total / 100) * 60)
    a4 = int((total / 100) * 80)

    A = [Y[i] for i in while_generator(0, a1)]
    B = [Y[i] for i in while_generator(a1,a2)]
    C = [Y[i] for i in while_generator(a2,a3)]
    D = [Y[i] for i in while_generator(a3,a4)]
    E = [Y[i] for i in while_generator(a4,(total - 1))]
    print("""Total of elements: {0}\n
    Conjunto A = {2} - Size {1}
    Conjunto B = {4} - Size {3}
    Conjunto C = {6} - Size {5}
    Conjunto D = {8} - Size {7}
    Conjunto E = {10} - Size {9}
    """.format(
        total,len(A),A,len(B),B,len(C),C,len(D),D,len(E),E
    ))
```

**Output:**

```
Total of elements: 120

            Conjunto A = [68, 68, 69, 68, 69, 70, 71, 75, 72, 73, 72, 72, 73, 72, 72, 73, 70, 71, 73, 72, 72, 71, 69, 68, 69]
            Conjunto B = [69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 68, 68, 68, 69, 68, 69, 70, 71, 75, 72, 69, 68, 68, 68, 69, 68, 69, 70, 71]
            Conjunto C = [71, 75, 72, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 68, 60, 60, 61, 60, 61, 65, 69, 69, 72, 73, 72, 72, 73]
            Conjunto D = [73, 72, 72, 73, 70, 71, 73, 75, 78, 80, 82, 84, 87, 84, 84, 83, 82, 79, 78, 76, 74, 73, 72, 72, 72]
            Conjunto E = [72, 71, 75, 72, 69, 68, 68, 68, 69, 68, 69, 70, 71, 75, 72, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 69, 68, 68]
```

**Print:**

[image]

Comment: Check out the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Comment: The suggestion is very good, but the problem is that it groups by the variation of the data, and not by the percentage that they represent in the whole